# How to stop a message loop in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need some help to stop a loop in discord.js (using node). This is my piece of code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.id === '601392330951491594') {
    if (message.content.startsWith('.idea')) {
      const clan = message.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'team-duty');
      const user = message.author;
      const messaggio = message.content.toString();
      const ListEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Messaggio di ${user.tag}`)
        .setDescription(messaggio)
      clan.send(ListEmbed);
      message.channel.bulkDelete(1)
      message.channel.send(`Messaggio inoltrato al gruppo staff (**${messaggio}**).`)
    }
  }
});
```

The problem here is that when I send a message starting with ".idea" the bot is keeping sending the messages in both channels. A strange thing is that when I send the message for the first time it sends just one message, and when I send the second/third message it starts looping.

With `console.log(JSON.stringify(message));`, I get this error message:

```
   console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
                    ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Client.client.on.message (C:\Users\Kikkiu\Desktop\DiscordKikBot\index.js:23:21)
    at Client.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Kikkiu\Desktop\DiscordKikBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Kikkiu\Desktop\DiscordKikBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Kikkiu\Desktop\DiscordKikBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Kikkiu\Desktop\DiscordKikBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Kikkiu\Desktop\DiscordKikBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Kikkiu\Desktop\DiscordKikBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
```

Comment: Sorry for my incompetence, but I'm new here. So it shouldn't loop because I put if(message.author.bot) return; at the start.

Comment: Did you try logging the `message`-object at the beginning?

Comment: Sorry again, but I have very little coding experience, but how do I do it?

Comment: Put `console.log(JSON.stringify(message));` between the first and second line of your code and edit your post with the console output that you are getting

Comment: Nope... same exact error. I'm wondering if I need to install some libraries to make this work.

Comment: Okay, then use `console.log(\`Message ${message.content} by a ${message.author.bot ? 'bot' : 'human'}\`);`

Comment: It works. When I send the first message, the bot sends one message in the console. When I send the second message, the bot sends 2 messages. When I send another message, the bot sends 3 messages, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by moving this piece of code in my index.json, I don't even know the nature of this problem. I didn't edit the code.